# App.Config Custom configuration section problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I've created a custom config section for my application. For some reason Visual Studio 2010 isn't picking up and of my custom properties. I'm getting warnings similar to this for all the "add" keys:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'urlFilterSection'
```

**CONFIG FILE:**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="urlFilterSection" type="BotFinderApp.Models.UrlFilterSection, BotFinder" />
</configSections>

<urlFilterSection>
    <urlFilterCollection>
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
        <add url="urlhere.com.au" numberOfIpsToExtract="10" />
    </urlFilterCollection>
</urlFilterSection>
```

**UrlFilterSection:**

```
namespace BotFinderApp.Models
{
    public class UrlFilterSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public UrlFilterSection()
        {    
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("urlFilterCollection", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(UrlFilterCollection), AddItemName = "add", ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
        public UrlFilterCollection Urls
        {
            get
            {
                var urlsCollection = (UrlFilterCollection)base["urlFilterCollection"];
                return urlsCollection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UrlFilterCollection**

```
namespace BotFinderApp.Models
{
    public class UrlFilterCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public UrlFilterCollection()
        {
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new UrlFilter();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((UrlFilter)element).Url;
        }
    }
}
```

**UrlFilter**

```
namespace BotFinderApp.Models
{
    public class UrlFilter : ConfigurationElement
    {
        public UrlFilter()
        {
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("url", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Url
        {
            get { return (string)this["url"]; }
            set { this["url"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("numberOfIpsToExtract", DefaultValue = "0", IsRequired = true)]
        public int NumberOfIpsToExtract
        {
            get { return (int)this["numberOfIpsToExtract"]; }
            set { this["numberOfIpsToExtract"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use it in you application? I mean, is it just compile time warnings or you can't even use it in you application?

Comment: UrlFilterCollection serviceConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("urlFilterSection") as UrlFilterCollection;

returns null...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem:

Decyclone was correct, errors were in fact just compile time warnings.

The real problem was I was accessing my configuration like this:

```
UrlFilterCollection serviceConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("urlFilterSection") as UrlFilterCollection;
```

when it should have been like this

```
UrlFilterSection serviceConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("urlFilterSection") as UrlFilterSection;
```

Thank you FlipScript and Decyclone :)

UPDATE:

I found out how to remove the compile time warnings - I'm using Visual Studio 2010. After creating my custom configuration section/s I used the "Create Schema" button from the toolbar which generates the schema file for the config. I then saved this to my project and the warnings disappeared.