# Merge .net configuration files

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

My application has 2 config files at the moment.

1. App.config
2. Custom.config

The App.config references the Custom.config via a custom section handler like below:

`<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="Custom" type="MyApp.CustomConfigSection, MyApp" />
  </configSections>
  <Custom configSource="Custom.config" />
</configuration>`

The problem is the Custom.config file contains a single section with many elements. I'd like to split this out so some of the elements are in one file and some are in another.

e.g. Right now I have

```
'<Custom>
     <Group1 ../>
     <Group2 ../>
     <Group3 ../>
</Custom>
```

I'd like to make 2 or more files like below.

```
'<Custom>
    <Group1 ../>
 </Custom>'

'<Custom>
     <Group2 ../>
     <Group3 ../>
 </Custom>'
```

At the moment I call ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Custom") as MyCustomConfigSection. I then have a number of classes with various configuration attributes that are populated automatically by the .net configuration.

Is there a way to do this split or can you not split 1 section into multiple files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: here's something to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718095/custom-app-config-section-with-a-simple-list-of-add-elements

Comment: thanks but all these examples are creating a custom config file per section. What I want to do is split a section into more than one config file and combine them at runtime.