# accessing a single item from custom config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

We are looking at following this sample which was very helpful:-
[Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718095/custom-app-config-section-with-a-simple-list-of-add-elements?answertab=active#tab-top)

however, can someone please assist with how to actually access the custom config item based on the name?

I realize that it is possible to do a for each and then get the correct one,  however, we would really like to access it like :-

```
config.Instances["Tata Motors"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the indexer of `ConfigurationElementCollection` is internal, you'll have to introduce your own indexer in `MyConfigInstanceCollection`:

```
public class MyConfigInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MyConfigInstanceElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        //set to whatever Element Property you want to use for a key
        return ((MyConfigInstanceElement)element).Name;
    }

    public new MyConfigInstanceElement this[string key]
    {
        get { return BaseGet(key) as MyConfigInstanceElement; }
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant, do you recommend any further reading material on this subject?

Comment: Thanks. I'm no expert in custom configuration but http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16724/Decoding-the-Mysteries-of-NET-Configuration seems rather comprehensive.