# Creating a custom List in app.Config. Reading and writing to the List

Tags: c#, list, app-config

I would like to create my own custom List in an app.config File. I am trying to have a list of Photos I would like to "pin" so That I could read this when the program runs Pinning my photos to the top of my list. I would then like to also have the ability to write to this list should any more photos be Pinned or unpinned.

So far I have:

```
  <PinnedPhotos>
    <Photo Location="location.jpg"/>
    <Photo Location="location2.jpg"/>
  </PinnedPhotos>
```

But I have no idea How to read or write to this List?

Comment: This is [the guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create custom configuration..

Comment: This guide was good, and I have managed to follow it. But it only shows how to create a single element in custom Config. I need to create a List of elements. My program crashes if I have 2 `Photos`

Comment: take a look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718095/custom-app-config-section-with-a-simple-list-of-add-elements)