# c# Syntax confusion with property, array, and method similarities on ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: c#

I was looking at this question

[Custom app.config section with a simple list of "add" elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718095/custom-app-config-section-with-a-simple-list-of-add-elements)

and I saw the following code for   SwDevMan81  answer

```
 public class MyConfigInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
 {
  public new MyConfigInstanceElement this[string elementName]
  {
     get
     {
        return this.OfType<MyConfigInstanceElement>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == elementName);
     }
  }
}
```

and I cant really figure out what this is called.

It appears to be a property with a get accessor, but then it holds a new keyword in front of the object type.   It appears to have an array indexer formed like method arguments.  I tired looking at the ConfigurationElementCollection  and ICollection but I didn't see anything that looked like this when I scanned the documentation.

What features is this ?

Comment: What feature is confusing you, exactly? The `new`? The indexer?

Comment: It's called an indexer. The [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) means that it's hiding the base class implementation. The base class `ConfigurationElementCollection` has it defined here (inherited from the ConfigurationElement class): [ConfigurationElementCollection.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Blorgbeard it was the indexer,  cant say i remember seeing it before in college and never messed with it before.   Just when I thought I was getting kinda good at programming a simple concept humbles me

Comment: @RufusL   Thanks for the explanation of the new keyword as well that lead me down to understanding the hiding of the method and what was really going on  If you make a answer i'll gladly accept it.

I'm think with the msdn documentation you are trying to show me that is how the indexer are documented. I find that documentation a little confusing as I dont know the purpose of the Item word in the   "Item[ConfigurationProperty]"  part of it means. going to the  ConfigurationElement documentation on it  helped clarify it as a indexer. We can dive into it more if you wish.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an `Indexer`

Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers