# How to read specific key from custom .config file in C#?

Tags: c#, config

I have a custom `.config` file which is below and wanted to read value of `ServerUrl` and update it. I can go till `AutoUpdate` but not sure how can I go to `Settings -> ServerUrl`.

**.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="AutoUpdate">
      <section name="Settings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <AutoUpdate>
    <Settings>
      <add key="Enabled" value="True" />
      <add key="ForceActivation" value="True" />
      <add key="Environment" value="Prod" />
      <add key="ServerUrl" value="https://Something.xml" />
      <add key="HourToCheckAutoUpdate" value="1" />
    </Settings>
  </AutoUpdate>
</configuration>
```

**Code:**

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"MyPath\My.config";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var b = config.GetSectionGroup("AutoUpdate"); // This returns "AutoUpdate".
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom app.config section with a simple list of “add” elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637544/6794089)

Comment: @bman7716 This is not a dup of that question. In your link, the config file is different then mine. I.e. `AppSettingsSection` is used there but not in mine. Also, example has `section -> key` while mime has `section->section->key`.

Comment: I see your point, but not for the reason you stated. Your issue isn't with the nested section keys, its the fact you are editing a config file your application doesn't own. I wrote up an answer for you that will get you what you need per your specific circumstances, however, @Stringfellow's answer should be preferred over mine if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

Update the **.Config** file to use 'AppSettingsSection':

```
<section name="Settings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
```

Use the following **Code** to obtain the properties:

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"MyPath\My.config";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var settingsSection = (AppSettingsSection) config.GetSection("AutoUpdate/Settings");
var enabled = settingsSection.Settings["Enabled"].Value;
var serverUrl = settingsSection.Settings["ServerUrl"].Value;
```

Comment: Even if I add `AppSettingsSection` in my config, this doesn't work. `settingsSection` comes null.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?
NameValueSectionHandler seems to be from the days of .NET 1.1.

Comment: @Stringfellow the `NameValueSectionHandler` is still valid, but only if you are working with a configuration file that the running application runs. The signatures differ for `GetSection` between `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` and `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration().GetSection()`. The first would allow you to convert/cast the section to a `NameValueCollection` where the second throws a compiler exception. IMO your answer is the preferred way to handle this, but since the config file can't be updated I posted an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be limited on what you can do. You aren't going to simply be able to read/convert the section that is flagged with the `NameValueSectionHandler` in the external config file. The `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(...).GetSection(...)` method inherits from a difference set of base classes and doesn't know how to handle the `NameValueSectionHandler`.

The best way to solve this is to flag your section to use the `AppSettingsSection` instead of the `NameValueSectionHandler` as detailed in @Stringfellow's answer, however, for whatever reason (probably good ones) you aren't able to do this.

As a result you are going to have to resort to working with the raw xml at some point. Below is an example of how to accomplish this.

```
// Gets your config section. It won't parse the xml to a 
// key/value structure, but does provide the raw xml
var b = config.GetSection("AutoUpdate/Settings"); 

var rawXml = b.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();

// Get the raw xml value and load it to a queryable XDocument object
var doc = XDocument.Parse(rawXml);
doc.Descendants("add")
    .Single(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "ServerUrl")
    .SetAttributeValue("value", "http://newthing.xml");

// Set the new xml back to the configuration object and persist the changes
b.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(doc.ToString());
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
```

A word of caution doing it this way is that you run a high risk of corrupting your config file(s) by mistake. Again, @Stringfellow's answer would be the preferred way of handling this.