# Store String Array In appSettings?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, app-config, asp.net-4.0

I'd like to store a one dimensional string array as an entry in my `appSettings`. I can't simply separate elements with `,` or `|` because the elements themselves could contain those characters.

I was thinking of storing the array as `JSON` then deserializing it using the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Is there a "right" / better way to do this?

(My `JSON` idea feels kinda hacky)

Comment: I recommend the Newtonsoft JSON stuff, if you go that route...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the AppSettings with a [`System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx).

```
var myStringCollection = Properties.Settings.Default.MyCollection;
foreach (String value in myStringCollection)
{ 
    // do something
}
```

Each value is separated by a new line.

Here's a screenshot (german IDE but it might be helpful anyway)

[image]

Comment: Can this be used for integers?

Comment: @akdurmus: only if you convert them to int: `int[] ints = new int[strings.Count]; for(int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++) ints[i] = int.Parse(strings[i]);`

Comment: I seem to find a better answer and posted below. Thank you @Tim

Comment: A typo in the code: `myStringCollection` vs. `myCollection`.

Answer (score 16):

ASP.Net Core supports it binding a list of strings or objects.

For strings as mentioned, it is possible to retrieve it through `AsEnumerable()`.

Or a list of objects via `Get<List<MyObject>>()`. The sample is below.

`appsettings.json`:

```json
{
 ...
   "my_section": {
     "objs": [
       {
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Object 1"
       },
       {
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Object 2"
       }
     ]
   }
 ...
}
```

Class to represent the object

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code to retrieve from `appsettings.json`

```cs
Configuration.GetSection("my_section:objs").Get<List<MyObject>>();
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. Previously tried simply 
getvalue and it was null

Comment: This is super helpful @Rodrigo.
What would the syntax look like to pick out an object having a specific id? Such as the one having "id":"2" ?

Answer (score 12):

For integers I found the following way quicker.

First of all create a appSettings key with integer values separated by commas in your app.config.

```
<add key="myIntArray" value="1,2,3,4" />
```

Then split and convert the values into int array by using LINQ

```
int[] myIntArray =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myIntArray"].Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 12):

For strings it is easy, simply add the following to your `web.config` file:

```
<add key="myStringArray" value="fred,Jim,Alan" />
```

and then you can retrieve the value into an array as follows:

```
var myArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myStringArray"].Split(',');
```

Comment: Did you mean `[...]` around `"MyStringArray"`, not `(...)`, or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be                                                                                         `var myArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyStringArray"].Split(',');`

Answer (score 7):

You may also consider using custom configuration section/Collection for this purpose.
Here is a sample:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="configSection" type="YourApp.ConfigSection, YourApp"/>
</configSections>

<configSection xmlns="urn:YourApp">
  <stringItems>
    <item value="String Value"/>
  </stringItems>
</configSection>
```

You can also check on this excellent [Visual Studio add-in](https://github.com/hybridview/ConfigurationSectionDesigner) that allows you to graphically design .NET Configuration Sections and automatically generates all the required code and a schema definition (XSD) for them.

Answer (score 7):

This may be what you are looking for:

appsettings storing the key NoLongerMaintained with an array of strings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "NoLongerMaintained": ["BCD",
    "DDP",
    "DHF",
    "DHW",
    "DSG",
    "DTH",
    "SCH"]
}
```

Then you may retrieve it as an array string[] using

```
var NoLongerMaintained = _config.GetSection("NoLongerMaintained").Get<string[]>();
```