# string multiple string value in one int variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to store multiple string value in one int variable

```
string OutReader = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutReader"].ToString();
int outrdr = Convert.ToInt32(OutReader);
```

The value of `AppSettings["OutReader"]` is: `"(1,2)"`

Comment: What value should `outrdr` have?

Comment: what is the current value in `AppSettings["OutReader"]`

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: AppSettings["OutReader"]="1,2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store String Array In appSettings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419116/store-string-array-in-appsettings)

Comment: In direct answer to your question, you can't. Absolutely can not. You might prefer to store it in a collection or array.

Comment: no effort to solve problem alone..

Comment: What value do you expect your `outrdr` to have? `1`, `2` or both or something else (please specify)? (Hint: both is impossible, unless you change the type to array or list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AppSettings["OutReader"]` currently have in it a string like: "(1,2)"
then you can do:

```
var sections = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutReader"].Replace("(",string.Empty)
                        .Replace(")",string.Empty)
                        .Split(',');
if(sections.Length > 0)
{
    int outrdr = Convert.ToInt32(sections[0]);
}
```

This can still throw an exception in the case that `section[0]` can't be parsed into an `int` so use `.TryParse` instead - Just wanted to stay as close to the question as possible

Comment: @Jay - please explain again what is currently not working. And when you do, please edit your original question (not adding a comment) with the current code and error you receive.

Comment: @Jay - the result is that `outrdr` contains the value `1` (starting from `(1,2)`). It is not possible to store the `2` as well in that single integer, but you can use `sections[1]` to access that using similar code.

Comment: string InReader = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InReader"].ToString();
                    string OutReader = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutReader"].ToString(); directly it is working